# WordPress import uses wrong date format

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm importing a lot of previously static pages into WordPress, all seem to be fine, but I encounter one weird problem.

According to [WordPress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post), the date format must be: `Y-m-d H:i:s`, and this is what I try to give it:

```
'post_date_gmt' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($data['date']))
```

But in WordPress itself it's recognized as `Y-d-m`, thus setting incorrect date and even adding some posts to "Scheduled".

What can cause this misunderstanding between us?

Comment: How are you importing and how `$data['date']` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `$data['date;]` ?

The function strtotime that you are wrapping around the $data['date'] expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.

see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Try without the strtotime()

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my date assembly before it was assigned to $data['date'] was incorrect.
I was adding strtotime($day.'/'.$month.'/'.$year) to it, but my PHP was making a US format time out of it, thus using my month as a day... Sorry, fixed. :)